# store meta data that can be overwrite thru inheritance

Tags: javascript

I am building a semi strong typed lua serializer using javascript.

The idea is to allow users to indicate the field/property type as meta data and use it during serialization similar to attributes in c#.

For example

```
class foo {
    property1 //Mark this as type number
    method1(){};
}

class bar {
    propFoo//Mark this as type foo
}
```

Yes i know the property definition is invalid syntax but I just want to express the idea.

Then `method1` should be defined on `bar.propFoo` when i deserialize `{ "propFoo" : { "property1" : 2} }` as bar

Descriptor seems like a natural fit but too bad it doesnt support custom description.

Then I looked at decorators and it seems promising. However I can't seem to figure out how to handle inheritance and overwrite.

For example

```
class foo{
   property1 //Mark this as type number
}

class bar extends foo {
   property1 //Overwrite and mark this as do not serialize/deserialize
}
```

Then when i try to deserialize `{ "property1" : 1 }` as `foo` it should have `property = 1` and `property1 = undefined` when i try to deserialize it as `bar`

prototype seems to be another possible solution since it handles the inheritance chain. However if i keep the type definition inside an object then any overwrite from inherited class will overwrite the one in base class too. (prototype inheritance doesnt create deep copy of the properties)

I am not being restricted on the `ES` version. So any new feature that can be transcompiled with `TypeScript` is acceptable!

Comment: So basically - [decorators](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators)?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum i mentioned it already. Can't figure out how to handle inheritance with decorators